# Getting specific PID from CentOS Journalctl

Tags: linux, bash

I'm writing a bash script that will print on the screen all the latest logs from a service that has already died (or still lives, both situations must work). I know its name and don't have to guess.
I'm having difficulty getting the latest PID for a process that has already died from journalctl. I'm not talking about this:

```
journalctl | grep "<processname>"
```

This will give me all the logs that include processname in their text.
I've also tried:

```
journalctl | pgrep -f "<processname>"
```

This command gave me a list of numbers which supposedly should include the pid of my process. It was not there.

These ideas came from searching for previous questions. I haven't found a question that answers specifically what I asked.

**How can I extract the latest PID from journalctl for a specific process?**

Comment: I don't think `pgrep` reads anything from standard input. Perhaps you'd like to explain what you hope for that command line to do in some more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.
First, you must be printing your PID in your logs. It doesn't appear there automatically. Then, you can use grep -E and awk to grab exactly the expression you want from your log:

```
Var=$(journalctl --since "24 hours ago" | grep -E "\[([0-9]+)\]" | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $5}' | awk -F"[][{}]" '{print $2}'
```

This one-liner script takes the logs from the last 24 hours, grep with -E to use an expression, tail -n 1 to grab the last most updated line from those results and then, using awk to delimit the line and grab the exact expression you need from it.

Comment: Your command can be simplified to `journalctl --since "24 hours ago" | awk '/\[[0-9]+\]/ {x=$5; gsub(/[][]/, "", x);} END {print x}'`. Perhaps see also [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)

Comment: Very useful @tripleee! Thanks :)